# Multer req.file.path is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, postman, multer

Sorry for this simple question. I'm just new to node.js and try to make a RESTapi with express. For file upload I'm using multer from npm. Everything is work fine. But when I try to access multer property in post method by using *req.file.path* it's throw this message:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Cannot read property 'path' of undefined"
    }
}
```

I also try to get other property available in multer like 'mimetype' but same error just property name changed. I'm using *postman* to send the data.
Here is my code snippets.

***product.js***

```
import express from 'express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import Product from '../models/product.model';
import multer from 'multer';

const router = express.Router();

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, './uploads');
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, `${new Date().toISOString().replace(/:/g, '-')}${file.originalname}`);
    }
});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
    // reject a file
    if(file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype === 'image/png') {
        cb(null, false);
    } else {
        cb(new Error('Only .jpeg or .png files are accepted'), true);   
    }
};

const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    limits: {
        fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5
    },
    fileFilter: fileFilter
});

router.post('/', upload.single('productImage'), (req, res, next) => {
    const product = new Product({
        _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        name: req.body.name,
        price: req.body.price,
        productImage: req.file.path
    });
    product.save().then(result => {
        console.log(result);
        res.status(201).json({
            message: 'Created product successfully',
            createdProduct: {
                name: result.name,
                price: result.price,
                _id: result._id,
                request: {
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: `http://localhost:3000/products/${result._id}`
                }
            }
        });
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({
            error: err
        });
    });
});
```

***product.model.ts***

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const productSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    price: {type: Number, required: true},
    productImage: { type: String, required: true }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
```

I can't find the solution. I've check a couple of solution from stackoverflow but didn't find any solution.

Comment: I don't see where you call `req.file.path` ?

Comment: Sorry. It was in post route. I've just try to get others available property from multer. See productImage: req.file.path on post method

Comment: Could you log `req.file` just before creating the new product and show us the output ?

Comment: @Striped that'll just come out undefined

Answer (score 0):

if you use postman make sure you select "Content-Type" "multipart/form-data" in the headers  and in the body make sure you select form-data and the key is  "productImage" and type is file then value is the file you want upload

Comment: Hmm, I do but no luck :(

Comment: can you try to require the module instead of importing it

Answer (score 0):

Sending file using cURL file name "image"

```
curl -X PUT  http://www.example.com  -F "image=@/file-path"
```

On server end get file name

```
upload(req, res, (err)=> {
            if (err) {
              console(err);
            }
            let filePath = req.files.image.file; // image is filename in cURL request
});
```